# Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens - R.java

Tags: android, layout, syntax-error, r.java-file

Location: line 1037

```
    public static final int @+f_tarifasID/cab_precio=0x7f070024;
```

I have a class in R.java (auto-generated) named f_tarifasID

> ```
> public static final class f_tarifasID {
>     public static final int aceptar=0x7f3a0006;
>     public static final int cab_nombre=0x7f3a0002;
>     public static final int cab_tarifa=0x7f3a0001;
>     public static final int cancelar=0x7f3a0007;
>     public static final int contenedorgrilla=0x7f3a0003;
>     public static final int grillaListView=0x7f3a0004;
>     public static final int layoutcabs=0x7f3a0008;
>     public static final int marcador=0x7f3a0005;
>     public static final int posicion=0x7f3a0009;
>     public static final int tituloform=0x7f3a0000; }
> ```

Layout.xml

```
...
        <NS.Android.ListGrillaView
            android:id="@+f_tarifasID/cab_precio"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="Precio"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />    
...
```

Now I can't compile my project, even if I delete @+f_tarifasID/cap_precio from layout, this error keeps in R.java

I have cleaned the project, I have deleted this line with another program... And still keeps here. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is about your variable names in the xml files. rename them according to traditional java naming conventions.

[you can read it here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: I have 200 variable names with the same pattern and they work fine. I have deleted f_tarifasID/cab_precio from layout and this error is still here.

Comment: try creating a new project then

Answer (score 0):

I solved it renaming "@+f_tarifasID/cab_pedido" to "cab_pedido" without @+ and cleaning my project one more time.